# How does path integral quantization ensure unitarity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, path-integral, unitarity

Unitarity can be verified post hoc by examining the optical theorem. In the context of path integral quantization where formal derivation starting from canonical quantization is unavailable, is it possible to determine if unitarity is guaranteed at the level of the Lagrangian?

I apologize if the question is not very specific.